# Try to toggle filter with 3 inputs value [Angular[

Tags: angular

I have 3 inputs when i clicked on once its send the value to the function, then the function filter the result and shot them in table.
I add a toggle button for case i press the button again to return previous result.

Everything work fine but i want to add the possibility when i clicked the first filter and then press the second filter i want the data rendered to the second filter and not toggle to the base result.

my Inputs:

```
  <button (click)="applyFilter('tax')">tax</button>
  <button (click)="applyFilter('money')">money</button>
  <button (click)="applyFilter('special')">special</button>
```

my Filter:

```
  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.filterBool = !this.filterBool;
    if (this.filterBool) {
      this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    } else {
      this.onGetReportsList(this.dataForFilter);
    }
  }
```

What the solution for this case?

Comment: This is hard to understand. Please show expected input and output.

Comment: In first click on button(filter) its show me the data of clicked filter, then when i clicked other filter it's toggle it and i need another click to view the other filter data and i expect that when i clicked other filter it's show me the data in one click and not 2 click

Answer (score 1):

```
//declare a property with the last entered value
let lastValue = "";
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {

if(this.lastFilter === 'tax'&& filterValue === 'money' )
 {
    this.lastValue = filterValue ;
    filterValue = 'tax';
 }
else()
{
  this.lastValue = filterValue ;
 this.filterBool = !this.filterBool;
}


if (this.filterBool) {
  this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
} else {
  this.onGetReportsList(this.dataForFilter);
}
```

}

Comment: In first click on button(filter) its show me the data of clicked filter, then when i clicked other filter it's toggle it and i need another click to view the other filter data and i expect that when i clicked other filter it's show me the data in one click and not 2 click